# How to display drop down menu when any text from whole page is selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display selection list menu when any text from any element is selected. I used "onselect" attribute but it seems to be only working only with "input" element. How can i show list similar to list when we right click anything on browser for every element?

It works when i select text in input element and not when i select text from h1 element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="myText">

<h1 onselect="myFunction()">Select some of the text: <input type="text" value="Hello world!" /></h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("You selected some text!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: If you could post your markup and script, it would be helpful for us to provide solution

Comment: Where is dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

The `onselect` works only for `input` and `textarea` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselect.

Instead you can use `onselectionchange` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event.

```js
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
    const {baseOffset, extentOffset} = document.getSelection();
    const node = document.getSelection().anchorNode;
    if(node) {
        const selectedText = node.data.slice(baseOffset, extentOffset);
        console.log(selectedText);
    }   
});
```

```html
<h1>Select some of the text: </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with mouseup event handler and window.getSelection() along with onselect event handler.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

Note that Selected text from window.getSelection() is slightly different due to browser.
It cannot be obtained from input/textarea element in most browsers.
(As far as I know, Only Chrome can obtain both input/textarea and other elements.)

Therefore, it is preferred that using a combination of onselect and mouseup event handler.
In mouseup handler, you have to omit input/textarea element to prevent handling selection event twice in some cases.

```
<h1>Select some of the text: <input type="text" value="Hello world!" /></h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("You selected some text!");
}

document.onselect = function() {
  myFunction();
}

document.onmouseup = function(e) {
  var element = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  if (!element || (element.tagName == 'INPUT') || (element.tagName == 'TEXTAREA')) {
    return;
  }

  var selObj = window.getSelection(); 
  var selText = selObj.toString();
  if (selText.length == 0) {
    return;
  }

  myFunction();
};
</script>
```

Comment: This seems to work. How is it possible to show a list of possible options on selection  from which user can select? selection list like when we right click on anything in browser?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of dropdown menu you are trying to show, but this library could be helpful.  
https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu